# What is the difference between .config() and .configure() in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm a beginner in Python. Recently, I finished the basics, and now I'm trying to make some GUI applications. I have found many cases where we use `config()` and `configure()`. But what is the difference between config() and configure()?

I mean, in what cases should `config()` be used, and in what cases should `configure()` be used? I have a small portion of my code here.

Code where Configure is used:

```
fontStyle = tkFont.Font(family="comic sans ms", size=15)


def zoomin_1():
    fontsize=fontStyle['size']
    fontStyle.configure(size=fontsize+5)


def zoomout_1():
    fontsize = fontStyle['size']
    fontStyle.configure(size=fontsize - 5)


def default_1():
    fontStyle.configure(size=10)
```

Code where `config` is used:

```
root.config(menu=mainmenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=Edit_menu)


Format_menu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff = False)
Format_menu.add_command(label="Word Wrap", command= test_fun)
Format_menu.add_command(label="Font", command= test_fun)
root.config(menu=mainmenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=Format_menu)
```

It would of great help if someone would clear this doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are exactly the same, the only difference is, the difference in the name, I would just reccomend using `.config()` just to save a few typing characters ;-)

Comment: It's definitely not measurably faster. At best it might be a picosecond faster.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find out the differences is to see the source code
of tkinter's `__init__.py`

(in my example it is in Thonny - `Thonny\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py`)

```
def configure(self, cnf=None, **kw):
    """Configure resources of a widget.

    The values for resources are specified as keyword
    arguments. To get an overview about
    the allowed keyword arguments call the method keys.
    """
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
config = configure
```

So they are the same